# how to build labels from the object key

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model that returns an object like this:

```
{type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"}
{type:"ford", model:"f250", color:"green"}
```

I need create a label from the object keys for example type, model, color and
a column that contains fiat, 500 etc.
I was trying to use:

```
model.map(elem=>{ Object.keys(elem)}
```

to get the keys but I am getting the keys of each item in the object. Is there any way to get the key value?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: can you give us an example of how you want the output

Comment: the output should be label1 = type, label2=model, label3 = color

Comment: Please edit the question to add your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the output should be label1 = type, label2=model, label3 = color

if you want to name them by label + nth

you can map over your cars then construct an object by looping over all the keys in a object.

if i have misunderstood please leave a comment and i'd be happy to change. :)

```js
const cars = [{
    type: "Fiat",
    model: "500",
    color: "white"
  },
  {
    type: "ford",
    model: "f250",
    color: "green"
  }
]


function getLabelsFromObject(model) {
  return Object.values(model).reduce(createLabelModel, {})
}

function createLabelModel(labels, label, i) {
  return Object.assign(labels, {[`label${i}`]: label})
}

console.log(cars.map(getLabelsFromObject))
```

Comment: I'd suggest that this is a misuse of `map`.  `reduce` would be more logical here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet changed it now looking alot nicer

Comment: Note that `Object.values` would clean this up just bit more.  But this is a nice solution as is, and I won't post my too-similar one.

Comment: Also note that `cars.map(getLabelsFromObject)` works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` gets you the keys.  You can use the keys to get the values like `myObject[key]`:

EDIT: Updated to produce desired output:

```js
const data = [
    {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"},
    {type:"ford", model:"f250", color:"green"}
]


const result = data.map(elem => {
    myKeys = Object.keys(elem)
    myResult = "";
    
    for (let x in myKeys) {
        myResult += "label" + (+x + 1) + "=" + myKeys[x] + ", ";
        // use elem[myKeys[x]] here to get the values (e.g. "Fiat", "500", "white")
    }
    return myResult;
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

Using `map()`, `Object.keys()` and `reduce()`:

```js
const car = [{type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"},
    {type:"ford", model:"f250", color:"green"}]

var res = car.map(item => {
  return Object.keys(item).reduce((a, c, i) => {
    a[`label${i+1}`] = item[c]
    return a;
  }, {});
});

console.log(res);
```

**OR:** [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The for...in statement iterates over all non-Symbol, enumerable properties of an object.

Using `map()`, `Object.keys()` and `for...in`:

```js
const car = [{type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"},
{type:"ford", model:"f250", color:"green"}]

var res = car.map(elem => { 
  var temp = {}, counter = 1;
  for(var k in elem){
    temp['label'+counter] = elem[k];
    counter++;
  }
  return temp;
});
console.log(res);
```